# Responsabilities of View

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, design-patterns, zend-view

After reflection over Fat models and Skinny Controlers (i have adopted), my question goes to view.

It's logic that :

- View read Rowset (Zend_Db_Table_Rowset), so object container, or an array of datas ?
- View test with Zend_Auth if user connected and show connect or disconnect pictures, or controller test with Zend_Auth and say if user is connected (like a simple data).
- View construct url to others controllers/Action, partially or totally without controller datas (plain Example : href="/users/delete/$id"), or view must create url with datas controller (ex : $urlFormat = "/users/delete/%s" and $id = x from controller, and view compose it ($id can be in array with most $id for example in list view, with links to action).

So, view has responsability to format datas, to html, or to xml, to be parsed. But where are borders responsabilities. If you have an article, i can read. Good documentation is very rare.

One more, sorry for my language, i don't write very goodly english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers:

- No. This should be done by the Controller which will pass the data to the view in a var(s)
- No. The controller should do all the tests. The auth test is surely a part of these control
- The vars/params should be tested by the controller and the url can be constructed by the view

I think you should read more about the MVC pattern (this is the pattern which has been implemented by the Zend Framework and many others). You can read about this pattern [here](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) or wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much agree with Aurelio. However, as for documentation not being too widely available, I have to disagree. Have a look at the list below, which contain both web links and links to text references all about MVC:

**Links:**

- [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller%20MVC%20Pattern)
- [Zend Framework + MVC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)
- [Zend Framework MVC Folders (ZendCasts)](http://www.zendcasts.com/zend-framework-mvc-folders/2008/12/)

**Books**

- [PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice 3rd Edition (Expert's Voice in Open Source)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Experts-Source/dp/143022925X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321972293&sr=1-1)
- [Pro PHP: Patterns, Frameworks, Testing & More: Patterns, Frameworks, Testing and More](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-PHP-Patterns-Frameworks-Testing/dp/1590598199/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321972293&sr=1-3)

Aurelio's answered your questions I believe, but here's some extra information. The Controller determines what should happen and put look after retrieving of information from the model.

The view however, isn't concerned with where information comes from, but takes care of the formatting. It's not responsible for connecting to databases, caching records or reading configuration information. I don't mean to be condescending in what I've said and hope that it doesn't come across that way.